# Problem removing a child level in script output

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a script that takes a json doc input which is flat and creates then a hierarchal output which sorts and groups submenus under the parents. Currently it works fine except that i need to make some changes to the output as the requirements have changed.

Currently children are output as child -items under parents.

```
 {
    enabled: true,
    guid: '1A9127A3-7AC7-4E07-AFA0-B8F8571B1B14',
    level: 0,
    name: 'Vendor',
    position: 0,
    child: {
      items: [
        {
          enabled: true,
          guid: '63A61762-75FB-466A-8859-25E184C3E016',
          level: 1,
          name: 'Add Vendor',
          position: 2
        },
        {
          enabled: true,
          guid: '6E6B4DA9-D99D-42D8-A4FE-7C7A82B9F1BE',
          level: 1,
          name: 'Vendor List',
          position: 1
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

I tried a few things but was only able to remove the child: from the first item, it did no longer have additional items.

```
function convert_json(input) {
    let max_level = 0;
    var sorted_by_level = {};

    input.forEach(i => {
      if (sorted_by_level.hasOwnProperty("level_" + i.level.toString())) {
        sorted_by_level["level_" + i.level.toString()].push(i);
      } else {
        sorted_by_level["level_" + i.level.toString()] = [i];
        if (i.level > max_level) {
          max_level = i.level;
        }
      }
    });
  
    for (level = max_level; level > 0; level--) {
      sorted_by_level["level_" + level.toString()].forEach(child => {
        const oldparent = sorted_by_level[
          "level_" + (level - 1).toString()
        ].filter(p => p.guid === child.parent)[0];
        const parentIndex = sorted_by_level[
          "level_" + (level - 1).toString()
        ].findIndex(p => p.guid === child.parent);
        let newparent;
    
        delete child.parent;
        delete child.umid;
        if (oldparent.hasOwnProperty("child") && oldparent.child.items) {
          newparent = {
            ...oldparent,
            child: { items: [...oldparent.child.items, child] }
          };
        } else {
          newparent = { ...oldparent, child: { items: [child] } };
        }
        sorted_by_level["level_" + (level - 1).toString()][
          parentIndex
        ] = newparent;
      });
    }
    sorted_by_level["level_0"].forEach(parent => {
      delete parent.umid;
      delete parent.parent;
    });
    var result = sorted_by_level.level_0 ;
    return result; 
  }
  function menu_sorted(input) { 
  let max_level = 0;
  var sorted_by_level = {};

  input.forEach(i => {
    if (sorted_by_level.hasOwnProperty("level_" + i.level.toString())) {
      sorted_by_level["level_" + i.level.toString()].push(i);
    } else {
      sorted_by_level["level_" + i.level.toString()] = [i];
      if (i.level > max_level) {
        max_level = i.level;
      }
    }
  });

  for (level = max_level; level > 0; level--) {
    sorted_by_level["level_" + level.toString()].forEach(child => {
      const oldparent = sorted_by_level[
        "level_" + (level - 1).toString()
      ].filter(p => p.guid === child.parent)[0];
      const parentIndex = sorted_by_level[
        "level_" + (level - 1).toString()
      ].findIndex(p => p.guid === child.parent);
      let newparent;
      
      if (oldparent.hasOwnProperty("child") && oldparent.child) {
        var mItems = [...oldparent.child, child];
        mItems.sort((a, b) => (a.position > b.position) ? 1 : -1);
        newparent = {
          ...oldparent,
          items: mItems
        };
      } else {
        newparent = {
          ...oldparent,
          items: [child]
        };
      }
      sorted_by_level["level_" + (level - 1).toString()][
        parentIndex
      ] = newparent;
    });
  }
  sorted_by_level.level_0.sort((a, b) => (a.position > b.position) ? 1 : -1);
  return sorted_by_level.level_0
}
console.log(util.inspect(convert_json(mydata.nofilter),false,null,true))
```

[Sample Code on REPLit](https://replit.com/@NoSoup4you2/Hierarchy-Fix?v=1)

Comment: What is the new expected result?

Comment: Same as the sample provided of what it is now just without the child [] array so that the child will be directly in the items{[] array without child

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, you want something like this:

```json
{
    enabled: true,
    guid: '1A9127A3-7AC7-4E07-AFA0-B8F8571B1B14',
    level: 0,
    name: 'Vendor',
    position: 0,
    items: [
      {
        enabled: true,
        guid: '63A61762-75FB-466A-8859-25E184C3E016',
        level: 1,
        name: 'Add Vendor',
        position: 2
      },
      {
        enabled: true,
        guid: '6E6B4DA9-D99D-42D8-A4FE-7C7A82B9F1BE',
        level: 1,
        name: 'Vendor List',
        position: 1
      }
    ]
}
```

For this, change the lines:

```js
if (oldparent.hasOwnProperty("child") && oldparent.child.items) {
  newparent = {
    ...oldparent,
    child: { items: [...oldparent.child.items, child] }
  };
} else {
  newparent = { ...oldparent, child: { items: [child] } };
}
```

to:

```js
if (oldparent.hasOwnProperty("items") && oldparent.items.length > 0) {
  newparent = {
    ...oldparent,
    items: [...oldparent.items, child]
  };
} else {
  newparent = { ...oldparent, items: [child] };
}
```

Let me know if I understood wrong and I will give it another go.